# Failed to import container images error fabric_e_invalid_operation

Tags: linux, azure, nginx, docker, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy a Linux container on Service Fabric Cluster with Linux (Preview) hosted on Azure.

I am having problem where I cannot run my Service Fabric Application with 1 `Nginx` service with following error:

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='Download:1.0:1.0'.
>   There was an error during download.Failed to download container image

I've investigate the log files and found some messages that seems correlated with the error:

```
2017-07-05 08:20:23.833,Info,29803,30481,Hosting.ProcessActivationManager,Processing Ipc message with action DownloadContainerImages
2017-07-05 08:20:23.834,Info,29803,30481,Hosting.DockerProcessManager,Starting dockerprocessmanager processName /usr/bin/docker, args daemon -H localhost:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
2017-07-05 08:20:23.834,Info,30547,30481,Common.ProcessWait,completed 0 waiters
2017-07-05 08:20:23.837,Info,29803,30481,Hosting.DockerProcessManager,Docker process has started. 29806
2017-07-05 08:20:23.850,Warning,30492,30481,Hosting.ContainerImageDownloader,Failed to get history for Image, error Failed to connect to any resolved endpoint
2017-07-05 08:20:23.850,Info,30492,30481,Hosting.ContainerImageDownloader,CheckDecrement count 0
2017-07-05 08:20:23.850,Warning,30492,30481,Hosting.ContainerActivator,Failed to import docker image error FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION.
2017-07-05 08:20:23.850,Info,30492,30481,Transport.Enqueue@7f4cbda4ef20,9aff2afa-8f9e-a34e-9d67-4bf57c605eb8:120476 true  125B @ qsize 0/0B
2017-07-05 08:20:23.850,Warning,30492,30481,Hosting.ProcessActivationManager,DownloadContainerImages returned FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION
2017-07-05 08:20:23.855,Info,29705,30566,Transport.Msg_Dispatch@7f42be16bc20,9aff2afa-8f9e-a34e-9d67-4bf57c605eb8:120476 true 1 125B
2017-07-05 08:20:23.855,Warning,29583,30566,Hosting.DownloadManager@9a8431474352dcc2e88fa9ad6af912b1:131437078006900280,Failed to import container images error FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION.
2017-07-05 08:20:23.855,Info,29583,30566,Hosting.DownloadManager@9a8431474352dcc2e88fa9ad6af912b1:131437078006900280,Download container images count 1 for activationcontext  error FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION.
2017-07-05 08:20:23.855,Warning,29583,30566,Hosting.DownloadManager@9a8431474352dcc2e88fa9ad6af912b1:131437078006900280,Download: Download:LinuxContainerServiceFabricApplicationType_App1:NginxGuestContainerPkg:1.0:1.0, ErrorCode=FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION, RetryCount=7
```

But I do not understand what is the reason it `Failed to get history for Image, error Failed to connect to any resolved endpoint`. Here is my `ServiceManifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="NginxGuestContainerPkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType.
         The UseImplicitHost attribute indicates this is a guest service. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="NginxGuestContainerType" UseImplicitHost="true" />
  </ServiceTypes>

  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <!-- Follow this link for more information about deploying Windows containers to Service Fabric: https://aka.ms/sfguestcontainers -->
      <ContainerHost>
        <ImageName>library/nginx:1.13.0-alpine-perl</ImageName>
      </ContainerHost>
    </EntryPoint>
    <!-- Pass environment variables to your container: -->
    <!--
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="VariableName" Value="VariableValue"/>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
    -->
  </CodePackage>

  <!-- Config package is the contents of the Config directoy under PackageRoot that contains an 
       independently-updateable and versioned set of custom configuration settings for your service. -->
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0" />

  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to 
           listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with 
           replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
      <Endpoint Name="NginxGuestContainerTypeEndpoint" Protocol="http" UriScheme="http" Port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

And my `ApplicationManifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest ApplicationTypeName="LinuxContainerServiceFabricApplicationType"
                     ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="NginxGuestContainer_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
  </Parameters>
  <!-- Import the ServiceManifest from the ServicePackage. The ServiceManifestName and ServiceManifestVersion 
       should match the Name and Version attributes of the ServiceManifest element defined in the 
       ServiceManifest.xml file. -->
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="NginxGuestContainerPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <Policies>
      <ResourceGovernancePolicy CodePackageRef="Code" CpuShares="500" MemoryInMB="1024" MemorySwapInMB="4084" MemoryReservationInMB="1024" />
      <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code">
        <RepositoryCredentials AccountName="someusername" Password="" PasswordEncrypted="false"/>
        <PortBinding ContainerPort="80" EndpointRef="NginxGuestContainerTypeEndpoint"/>
      </ContainerHostPolicies>
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <!-- The section below creates instances of service types, when an instance of this 
         application type is created. You can also create one or more instances of service type using the 
         ServiceFabric PowerShell module.

         The attribute ServiceTypeName below must match the name defined in the imported ServiceManifest.xml file. -->
    <Service Name="NginxGuestContainer">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="NginxGuestContainerType" InstanceCount="[NginxGuestContainer_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

Can you help me point out what am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

**Update**

I am not sure whether this is causing the issue or not, but when I do SSH to the one of the SF node, I've found that the Docker service are `stopped`. When I try to start it and do a manual `pull`, one minute later it will stop automatically. Here is the logs from `systemctl`:

```
Jul 05 09:25:51 default000000 dockerd[41096]: time="2017-07-05T09:25:51.835329455Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jul 05 09:25:51 default000000 dockerd[41096]: time="2017-07-05T09:25:51.946744849Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jul 05 09:25:51 default000000 dockerd[41096]: time="2017-07-05T09:25:51.946809649Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=02c1d87 graphdriver=aufs version=17.06.0-ce
Jul 05 09:25:51 default000000 dockerd[41096]: time="2017-07-05T09:25:51.961652188Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Jul 05 09:25:51 default000000 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 05 09:26:53 default000000 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Jul 05 09:26:53 default000000 dockerd[41096]: time="2017-07-05T09:26:53.919115662Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Jul 05 09:26:53 default000000 dockerd[41096]: time="2017-07-05T09:26:53.954315756Z" level=info msg="stopping containerd after receiving terminated"
Jul 05 09:26:54 default000000 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 05 09:26:55 default000000 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ContainerHost>
    <ImageName>library/nginx:1.13.0-alpine-perl</ImageName>
  </ContainerHost>
```

Seems suspect...  Is this resolvable?  Your log stated:

2017-07-05 08:20:23.850,Warning,30492,30481,Hosting.ContainerImageDownloader,Failed to get history for Image, error Failed to connect to any resolved endpoint

I'm doing something similar with the AzureCR

```
  <ContainerHost>
    <ImageName>xxxxxx.azurecr.io/hedge-app:298</ImageName>
  </ContainerHost>
```

Can you pull the image from the CLI ?

Comment: Yes I am able to pull the `library/nginx:1.13.0-alpine-perl` image from CLI.